# SQL Injection related:Why does my SQL query return only part of value with concatenate?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I am trying to understand what my problem is. Maybe I do not understand how the concatenate works? 
In MySQL version 5.5.40-0+wheezy1 the following happens:

```
firstname='something'
salt='123456'
```

The normal query in php is

```
UPDATE users SET firstname='$name' WHERE id=:uid;
```

I try to SQL inject into the firstname area:

```
'+ (SELECT s FROM (SELECT salt as s FROM users WHERE username='something') AS saltEntry)+'
```

So full query is

```
UPDATE users SET firstname=''+ (SELECT s FROM (SELECT salt as s FROM users WHERE username='something') AS saltEntry)+'' WHERE id=:uid;
```

The result is only in the firstname area `12` or `123` but never the full string.

Also when I enter:`test'+ (SELECT s FROM (SELECT salt as s FROM users WHERE username='something') AS saltEntry)+'`

it also just returns `12` or `123` as the first name.

But when I try it out in the SQL server without ' or +: `UPDATE users SET firstname= (SELECT s FROM (SELECT salt as s FROM users WHERE username='something') AS saltEntry) WHERE id=:uid;` 
It copies the entire salt into the firstname entry and it works.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

EDIT1: 
Well according to @eggyal if this MySQl then + is only arithmetic operator. I can not use `Concat()` because of the single quote ' starting. How do you then insert the subquery into the query?

ANSWERED: @eggyall in the comments.

Comment: Despite both having the "SQL" acronym in their names, MySQL (owned by Oracle Corporation) and SQL Server (owned by Microsoft) are entirely different programs. I've fixed question tags accordingly.

Comment: In SQL, `+` is the arithmetic addition operator—not string concatenation.

Comment: So I can only use CONCAT()? @eggyal Then how is injection possible while closing the ' ?

Comment: You could, for example, update multiple columns.  Eg, `UPDATE users SET firstname = '` then inject `', surname = (SELECT ...), middleInitial = '`, completed by `' WHERE id=:uid;`.  You could even update the `firstname` column a second time and use a user variable to discard the final quote, i.e. by injecting `', firstname = (SELECT ...), @dummy = '`.

Comment: Or, if the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) SQL mode happens to be enabled, you could use the `||` operator to perform string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you @eggyal! This is correct. I was stuck in a hole with concatenate. 'DUH I am a dummy' Thank you for helping a newbie with SQL/PHP/Injection!

Answer (score 1):

### Use CONCAT():

You could use concat() function to concatenate more that one string and pass the firstname and salt as parameters to get the desired result:

```
UPDATE users SET firstname= CONCAT(firstname, (SELECT s FROM (SELECT salt as s FROM users WHERE username='something') AS saltEntry)) WHERE id=:uid;
```

Comment: Good luck injecting `CONCAT(` before the opening quote of the (intended) string literal!

Comment: It's not clear to me in the question if he wants to concatenate the string value of the SQL or not, so my answer is based on the evaluation of the SQL and not the SQL itself.

Comment: Well yes I wanted to concatenate but moreso to inject this subquery I had. The answer was to , not +. Thank you for helping @ShadiShaaban

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that '+' is an operator that can be applied to numbers only. It doesn't concatenate two values, but sums them. Now, when you apply it to a string, MySQL first converts the string to a number (which is always equal to 0) and adds the value to the next operand. So, you always end up with a result that is equal to the numeric operand (if you have any).

As you already figured, CONCAT is the right option to use here.

If you don't specifically need to append the select string to the query, I'd suggest improving it a bit, in order to avoid too many nested queries in there.

Since you do an update, you can't have a value that's a result of a nested query to the same table. But, you can use join, which would make your query much less complex and more optimal.

```
UPDATE users as original 
JOIN users as salts USING(user_id) 
SET original.firstname = CONCAT({$first_name},salts.salt) 
WHERE salts.username='something'
```

Comment: I think you've missed the point, that the OP is trying to inject SQL through an unescaped string literal.

Comment: Maybe, I thought the OP was asking on how to inject it because it was the only way that came to his/her mind, not that it's the specific request. I figured knowing this would be helpful, but I couldn't comment because I still don't have enough reputation to do so, so I pasted it as a separate answer :)